# Problems with GetCursorPos

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directx

I'm having problems with GetCursorPos. I use directx to draw a square where the cursor is but my code doesn't work and I have no idea why...

```
LPPOINT cursorPos = 0;
GetCursorPos(cursorPos);
square->setPosition(D3DXVECTOR2(40.0f,60.0f));  // as a test: works fine...
square->setPosition(D3DXVECTOR2(cursorPos->x, cursorPos->y)); // -> crash
```

I also tried this:

```
LPPOINT cursorPos = 0;
GetCursorPos(cursorPos);
float posX = cursorPos->x;  // no crash...
float posY = cursorPos->y;  // no crash...
std::cout << posX << posY <<std::endl; // CRASH!
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you declare an `LPPOINT`, you're declaring a pointer to a `POINT` object. Therefore, when you write

```
LPPOINT cursorPos = 0;
```

You're creating a pointer called `cursorPos` and setting it to `NULL`. The call

```
GetCursorPos(cursorPos);
```

then fails, because `GetCursorPos` expects you to provide a pointer to the `POINT` that you want to fill in with the information and you've provided a `NULL` pointer. Consequently, when you write

```
square->setPosition(D3DXVECTOR2(cursorPos->x, cursorPos->y)); // -> crash
```

You're reading a `NULL` pointer when trying to read `x` and `y`. This leads to undefined behavior, which here is a crash. In the other case, you're also getting undefined behavior, and it just happens to not crash.

To fix this, try declaring an actual `POINT` object, like this:

```
POINT cursorPos;
```

then calling

```
GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
```

then reading the position as

```
square->setPosition(D3DXVECTOR2(cursorPos.x, cursorPos.y));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought GetCursorPos would declare the object because I found it like this in a tutorial... Seems stupid now! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @theCNG27, Ouch, there are a lot of tutorials with plain wrong code. Knowing a fair amount of C++ first goes a long way.